# Unknown component place on a switching converter PCB

Tags: identification, components, switching, converter

I bought a [220V to 12V converter](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AC-DC-Converter-AC110v-220v-230v-To-DC-12v-5w-Power-Switching-Transformer-Module-/253152593951) and behind the PCB there's place for a component named U3:

[image]

It's not a [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) series because their output pin is the middle pin, and not a [78XX series](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf) because on the PCB input and output are not matching.

What U3 is for?

Comment: At £1.79 each you are not going to get a data sheet from ebay and that might be the only way you could find out without reverse engineering the circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka Thought maybe someone could guess by experience...

Comment: But what use is guessing - are you somehow hoping that you can make an improvement to the circuit and thus for £1.79 plus a couple more parts you get something that is a miracle of the modern world? What is the point of this?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm hoping that it's a place for voltage regulator so I can change some of the 12 V modules that I have to 5V.

Comment: They are £1.79 each - go buy one that is 5 volt out.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes easiest solution is that.

Comment: That thing is dangerous (as is usual for cheap power supplies from Ebay/DX/etc); it has far too little isolation distance between the high voltage side and the low voltage side.

Comment: @marcelm Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this unit and other almost identical units, U3 is a place for a linear regulator to get multiple output voltages. Any component that has a matching pinout and package could be used.

Comment: Which voltage regulators have the same pin order? I'm only familiar with ams1117 and 78XX series...

Comment: There are millions of voltage regulators. I am not familiar with all of them either.

Comment: [Found it.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua78l.pdf)